# Is there a specific meaning behind the bomb planting code 7355608?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When terrorists plant the bomb during a round of counter-strike go, the activation code `7553608` is entered. This code is always the exact same. Is there any reason for this specific code?

Comment: 7355608 is 7 digits long, 7+3+5+5+6+0+8 = 34, 34 + 7 = 41, 4 - 1 = 3 - Half Life 3 confirmed.

Comment: @kalina [:p](https://steamdb.info/sub/66300/)

Comment: @kalina https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/213h4q/why_is_7355608_the_bomb_code_80m65_537_bombs_set/cg9j8ez >_>

Comment: why is this question getting upvotes when it is clearly off-topic as said here "Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative. You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE, but be sure to read their FAQ"

Comment: @Dragonrage, remove the sentence on developers, and you have a perfectly acceptable question. This should **not** be answered with developer speculation, but asking if there is a meaning behind something in the game is not off topic, as it may be answerable with in game knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

`7355608` in *[leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)* is "*tessboB*".

If you read that backwards you get "*Bobsset*".

That looks a lot like "Bomb's set" which is what happens when you've entered in the code. It's just missing an *m*. Which is actually a bit more complicated to translate to leet, the translation being `(\/)` which wouldn't be able to be written with numbers.

I guess that throws that theory out the window...

Oh wait:

[image: Css bomb]

In conclusion, it's plausible that the code and the model number for the bomb in the Counter Strike series can mean: **"*Bomb's set*"**.

Comment: Is this a joke post, or do you have a source for this? It seems unlikely that they'd use two separate numbers for 'B'  **{Edit}** The source seems to be [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/213h4q/why_is_7355608_the_bomb_code_80m65_537_bombs_set/), which was in turn taken from [this forum](http://www.vakarm.net/forums/topic/Le-code-de-la-bombe/12054).  It's a joke.

Comment: It's not a joke, it's a theory or speculation. the two different numbers for b is because one is a capital as it's the start of the phrase, which is useful as it helps you to discover to read it backwards. Developer's have been hiding small things like this since the dawn of gaming, it's possible that this was their intention as it does seem to make sense.

Comment: You should not be listing theory or speculation as an answer. You should also never answer with developer intent, given that developer intent is completely off topic on this site.

Comment: @Timelord64 why not? what's wrong with theory and speculation? where's it say I can't? Question asked what's special about this code on the bomb, I said that if you assume it's leet and read it backwards it spells out something related to bomb's. What's wrong with that? Does it not answer the question? I didn't answer with developer intent, that's a comment. My answer mentions nothing about developers, it just shows a way of making sense of some numbers and a letter.

Comment: Asking for theory and speculation is off topic. As such, either a - this entire question is off topic and should be closed (at the time of you answering, that was the case) or b - the OP was not asking for your theory and speculation, and as such, it is of no use to the context of the question. It is alright to say "If you spell it in leet it says bomb". That is not speculation, that is observation. Saying "wait, where is the m? oh its somewhere on the same device - **that must have been what the developers were intending** is just your speculation, and it appears very.. weak.

Comment: Also, this reads more like a forum post then it does an answer. I have just realised you have taken this almost entirely from reddit, but we expect a little bit more then "there is an m on the same model, I can rearrange the m into the numbers to spell bomb, so that must be what the developers meant"

Comment: It's too much of a coincidence to not be some form of intentional

Comment: @Timelord64 You're over-analyzing this. Sure, this information was taken from reddit, but that absolutely does not invalidate anything. Everything has a source. And I'd hardly call the part about the letter M the focus of the answer. This is a perfectly legitimate way to answer the question. And you can't argue this to be opinion-based _or_ developer-related because you'd have to prove it first.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer valve is pretty good at hiding stuff. Probably intentional.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: If that's actually what they intended, they wouldn't have reversed the order or arbitrarily removed letters.  This post reads like a conspiracy theory, not the well-researched answers we expect here.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft sure, i'm not judging the answer on it's validity or not, just stating the the coincidences is highly improbable if it's just random, doing the math for permutations of 1-0 seven times, it's 10 million possible combinations, so 1:10,000,000 is an odd coincidence, and the letter M on the bomb has no other meaning, HOWEVER, I didn't upvote this because the bomb in the picture is from CS:S, in CS:GO there is no "M" on the bomb